# Save Custom Workout Data With SwiftData

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, healthkit, swift-data

I am currently developing an app for iOS 17/watchOS 10 which is basically a workout app that synchronizes data with the new Swift API for workout mirroring (`func startMirroringToCompanionDevice(completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void)`).

However, I tried several approaches to save data the user inputs himself during the workout after setting up the CloudKit container:

- I marked all my classes as `@Model`, but this would create duplicate entries in the CloudKit container when sending the data from iPhone to Apple Watch and vice versa.
- I made similar classes without the use of `@Model` for the currently running workout from the SwiftData models, but this seems not like a good approach because of duplicated code in my opinion.
- I tried to save my custom data with the `HKWorkout` itself but as far as I know there is no way of saving any custom metadata?

I would appreciate any input on this topic as this is my first project with Swift development. I would also like to run the app as iPhone only/Apple Watch only app, but syncing the data between the devices and saving it appropriatelly is my main focus at the moment.

Comment: Why not share the container? A watch can share/not share with the main app if they just have the same url you can also remove any duplicated code with protocols

Comment: @loremipsum I was not aware of that, thank you very much. As I said I am quite new to swift so I apologize if the question itself seems a bit stupid.

Comment: It isn't stupid at all, very legitimate issue and something you wouldn't think of if you are new. Just keep in mind "single source of truth"  if you are duplicating anything when programming there is always a better way.

Comment: I have a similar problem. If I add a new item to the container, how would you automatically fetch and open a detail page or similar from that item on the watch?